# ¿Cómo acceder a este arreglo de objetos en PHP, imprimiendo cada valor?

Tags: php, array, objeto

Arreglo que recibo en mi función de PHP:

```
       configuracion = {
            situaciones:[
                {idu_configuracion: null, idu_situacion: null}
            ],
            productos:[
                {idu_configuracion: null, idu_producto: null, nom_producto:null, pje_descuento:null, des_penultimodigito:null, clv_producto:null}
            ],
            ciudades:[
                {idu_configuracion:null, idu_estado: null, idu_ciudad: null, nom_estado:null, nom_ciudad:null}
            ]
        }
```

El objeto 'Productos' puede contener n arreglos, lo que quiero es imprimir cada arreglo con un ciclo, en mi función de PHP:

```
public function guardarConfiguracion()
{
    $configuracion = null; //Recibo mi arreglo de objetos
        foreach ($configuracion->productos in $producto) {
                print "$producto";
            }

}
```

Comment: ese objeto que mencionas no es de PHP verdad ?  Parece un Object de JS.

Comment: Es de JS, lo recibo en una función de PHP

Comment: cuando lo ecibas hazle un `json_decode` y solo usas los indices que deseas

Comment: Tienes un ejemplo del código PHP que está recepcionando los datos? Si nos lo muestras lo podremos adaptar a lo que necesitas.

Comment: Ya lo agregué..

Comment: entonces cada hijo de $producto puede ser un valor o un array que tenga más hijos?

Comment: Con ese codigo me marca error, pero mi intencion es que cada $producto sea un arreglo con todos los atributos de un solo producto para poder hacer un insert de cada producto almacenado.

Comment: No te funciona por que debes hacer un `json_encode($_POST['campo'])` y el json que pases debe estar bien formado. esto te dira si esta bien hecho o no el JSON https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta de esta forma:

```
<?php 

echo configuracion.productos['idu_configuracion'];

?>
```